# Join needed in SQL Server 2008, I'm just lost

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've programmed in SQL from 1992-1999. I'm getting myself in a pickle in a new "training" job, in SQL Server 2008, as I haven't programmed in 15 years.

I know I'm going about stuff the "long way round". Could you have look at this for me please?

Two tables:

`LANG_MASTER`:

```
text_ID    Country_ID    Master_Text
------------------------------------
  45          166        Counta
  45           65        Count
  67          166        Region
  67           65        Reginia
  78           65        Field
  78          166        Field
```

`NEW_TRANSLATIONS`:

```
English      Translation    Country ID    Status
------------------------------------------------
Count        Countee           166           0
Region       Provinicia        166           0
Field        Felda             166           0
House        Casa              166           0
```

I need to update `New_Tranlations.status` to 3 as follows:

- New-Translations.English = Lang_Master.Master_Text..........(Text_ID = X)
- Lang_Master.County_ID = 166.......Text_ID = X
- New_translations.translation <> Lang_master.master_text

Basically if there is a translation in the master table but it is different to the translation in the new_translation table I need to mark it as '3'

e.g. result required :

`NEW_TRANSLATIONS`:

```
English      Translation    Country ID     Status
-------------------------------------------------
Count        Countee           166            3
Region       Provinicia        166            3
Field        Felda             166            0
House        Casa              166            0
```

This is as far as I've got:

```
update new_translations
set status = 3 
where translation in
    (select LM.master_text
    from lang_master as LM
        , new_translations as NT
     where  NT.english <> LM.text_ID
      and LM.country_id = 65  
     and LM.text_ID in 
  ( select LM.text_id 
    from lang_master as LM
         ,new_translations as NT
    where LM.master_text = NT.translation
    and LM.country_id = 166))
```

I know this is all wrong but I just cant see what to do! Please help!

Comment: What links lang_master to new_translations other than country id? Does textID also exist in new_translations?

Comment: And what was the result of the above `update` statement?  What does new_translations look like now?

Comment: Probably, row field-felda-166 should me marked with status 3 as well?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood you problem, your query should look like this:

```
UPDATE new_translation n1 SET status = 3 WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT m1.text_id, m1.country_id c1, m1.master_text mt1, m2.country_id c2, m2.master_text mt2 
   FROM lang_master m1 INNER JOIN lang_master m2
   ON m1.text_id = m2.text_id and m1.country_id > m2.country_id
   WHERE n1.country_id = m1.country_id AND m1.master_text <> n1.translation 
     AND m2.master_text = n1.english 
);
```

And here is fiddle to try it out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab3c0d/1

Answer (score 0):

I am suppposing that you can join based on the below common fields between `lang_master` and `new_translations` table

```
text_id
Country_id
```

Then the below query can help:

```
update NT 
set status = 3 
FROM lang_master lm JOIN new_translations nt
ON lm.text_id = nt.text_id
and lm.Country_ID = nt.Country_ID
and lm.master_text <> nt.translation
```

If the joining columns are different, just update the join condition. But more or less, something on the lines of above would do the job.